# Not able to edit the mock with jest.mocked

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs, expo

I'm working on this React Native project - which means that since some of the modules are "native" code (not JS/TS) they need to be mocked out. I want to mock the `.getItemAsync` so that it in some tests it returns `undefined` and in others a string like `"some@email.com"`.

Got a test file that looks like:

```js
// SignInScreen.test.ts
...
import SignInScreen from './index'
...
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store'
jest.mock('expo-secure-store')
const mockedSecureStore = jest.mocked(SecureStore, true)
mockedSecureStore.getItemAsync.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve('IN TEST FILE: BEFORE ALL TESTS'))

...

  describe('signed in previously', () => {
    it.only('gets the email from local storage', async () => {
      const mockedSecureStore = jest.mocked(SecureStore, true)
      mockedSecureStore.getItemAsync.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve('IN TEST FILE: WITHIN TEST'))
      // @ts-ignore
      const utils = TestHelper.renderWithReactQueryClient(<SignInScreen />)
    })
```

```js
// stores/credentials.ts
...
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store'
...
console.log({ SecureStore })
SecureStore.getItemAsync('EMAIL').then((email) => console.log('EMAIL', { email }))
```

[image: jest output]

```bash
console.log
    {
      SecureStore: {
        __esModule: true,
         ...
        getItemAsync: [Function: getItemAsync] {
          _isMockFunction: true,
          getMockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)],
          mock: [Getter/Setter],
          mockClear: [Function (anonymous)],
          mockReset: [Function (anonymous)],
          mockRestore: [Function (anonymous)],
          mockReturnValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
          mockResolvedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
          mockRejectedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
          mockReturnValue: [Function (anonymous)],
          mockResolvedValue: [Function (anonymous)],
          mockRejectedValue: [Function (anonymous)],
          mockImplementationOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
          mockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)],
          mockReturnThis: [Function (anonymous)],
          mockName: [Function (anonymous)],
          getMockName: [Function (anonymous)]
          ...
```

What am I missing?

---

I can do something like this:

```js
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store'
jest.mock('expo-secure-store', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  getItemAsync: () => Promise.resolve('IN TEST FILE BEFORE ALL TESTS'),
}))
```

(then use the `jest.mocked()` to help with the typing)

But are not able to change it further down:

```js
  describe('signed in previously', () => {
    it.only('gets the email from local storage', async () => {
      jest.resetAllMocks()
      SecureStore.getItemAsync.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve('IN TEST FILE: WITHIN TEST'))
      // @ts-ignore
      const utils = TestHelper.renderWithReactQueryClient(<SignInScreen />)
    })
```

---

attemps like

```js
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store'
const mockSecureStore = jest
  .spyOn(SecureStore, 'getItemAsync')
  .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve('IN FILE: BEFORE ALL TEST'))
...

  describe('signed in previously', () => {
    it.only('gets the email from local storage', async () => {
      mockSecureStore.getItemAsync.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve('IN TEST FILE: WITHIN TEST'))
      // @ts-ignore
      const utils = TestHelper.renderWithReactQueryClient(<SignInScreen />)
      jest.clearAllMocks()
    })
```

this fails to mock out the SecureStore

[image]

Comment: What do you mean _edit_ the mock with `jest.mocked`? It's a no-op function, it only changes the _type_: https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockedtitem-t-deep--false

Comment: I want to be able to mock the `.getItemAsync` so that it is some test returns `undefined` and in others `some@email.com`

Comment: Found the `jest.mocked` from the docs you linked to. I read it as it's giving a reference to the mocked and adding types to it.

Comment: doing `import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store'` and `jest.mock('expo-secure-store')` followed by `SecureStore.getItemAsync.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve('IN TEST FILE: BEFORE ALL TESTS'))` does not work either (but TS complains yes)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have posted an answer where I use the `jest.mocked()` to edit the initial mock

Comment: Again, that's a no-op function that only impacts the _types_ the compiler sees. It doesn't in any way edit the argument.

Comment: I don't know what that means? haven't heard about no-op before

Comment: It's just the identity function, at runtime simply `(thing) => thing`. It's a [no-op](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code)). See [the implementation](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/811228d6ae73a6563a98b0ee36b73f453e644f2f/packages/jest-mock/src/index.ts#L1229-L1236).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got something to work that looks like this:

```js
// SignInScreen.test.ts
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store'

jest.mock('expo-secure-store', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  getItemAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('IN FILE: BEFORE ALL TEST')),
}))

...

  describe('signed in previously', () => {
    it.only('gets the email from local storage', async () => {
      const mockedSecureStore = jest.mocked(SecureStore, true)
      mockedSecureStore.getItemAsync.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve('IN FILE: WITHIN TEST'))

      // @ts-ignore
      const utils = TestHelper.renderWithReactQueryClient(<SignInScreen />)
      jest.clearAllMocks()
    })
```

```js
// stores/credentials.ts
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store'
...
SecureStore.getItemAsync('credential store').then((email) => console.log('credential store', { email }))
```

```js
// SignInScreen.ts
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store'

export default (props: RootStackScreenProps<'SignIn'>) => {
  ...
  SecureStore.getItemAsync('FROM SIGN IN').then((email) => console.log('FROM SIGN IN', { email }))

  return <View....
}
```

```bash
  console.log
    credential store { email: 'IN FILE: BEFORE ALL TEST' }

      at stores/credentials

  console.log
    FROM SIGN IN { email: 'IN FILE: WITHIN TEST' }

      at screens/SignInScreen
```

Learnings:

- Can only overwrite the package methods (`expo-secure-store`) if they is used in a function
- Can not overwrite mock later they are called directly within my scripts (since they seem to have already been imported with the initial mock)
- have to use the `jest.mock`, couldn't get `jest.spyOn().mockImplementation` to work.